# Play framework: type Integer is deprecated: use java.lang.Integer instead

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Since PlayFramework doesn't seem to allow primitive java types (e.g int, long) in routes, I've had to resort to using `Integer` in the routes, e.g:

```
GET /paginate/:page controllers.Foo.paginate(page: Integer)
```

However, when starting the app, I get a ton of warnings saying:

```
[warn] /project/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/routes_reverseRouting.scala:351: type Integer is deprecated: use java.lang.Integer instead
[warn] def paginate(page:Integer) = new play.api.mvc.HandlerRef(
```

Wtf is this about? Do I now have to specify `java.lang.Integer` in all my routes? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Int` instead?

Comment: What specific version of play? Did you try `Int`?

Comment: 2.0.4. No, I haven't tried Int. Is that a native java type or scala / play specific?

Comment: `Int`, a 32-bit signed integer (equivalent to Java's int primitive type). Reference here http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int

Comment: Great, I wonder how many other scala specific things have to be learnt to use Play. Anyway, please post the answer to use `Int` and I'll accept

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269170/what-is-are-differences-between-int-and-integer-in-scala gives good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

1) In the routes file: replace "Integer" with "Int". 
   You may want to specify a default value. Example:

```
GET  /my/path  controllers.MyController.foo(value:Int ?= 0)
```

2) In the (Java) controller: change Integer to int

```
public static Result foo(int value) {}
```

I found the warning "type Integer is deprecated: use java.lang.Integer instead" very confusing too.

Comment: Thank you man, your answer help us, i do not know more about scala but i love Play Framework.