# How does Scala handle tuples containing JVM primitive values?

Tags: scala, jvm

I have tried these two variables:

```
val km = (1,2,4.3,false)

val klpd = (1,2)
```

In the second case I see `Tuple2[Int,Int]` but the first case shows `Tuple4[Integer,Integer,Double,Boolean]` in the memory i.e. seeing the variable type in Intellij/Eclipse.

So Scala is dumping the primitive type Int and storing it as Integer.

Same is seen if I add an Int to `Array[AnyVal]`.

PS: I am using Scala 2.10.4 and my REPL output doesn't match that of Eclipse..

Comment: What version of Scala are you using?  I get `km: (Int, Int, Double, Boolean) = (1,2,4.3,false)` in 2.11.2's REPL.

Comment: Also, `Int != int` - `Int` is `scala.lang.Int` while `Integer` is `java.lang.Integer`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1271990/135978) for more details.

Comment: Will update my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Scala, tuples are represented using classes taking generic type parameters. There are 22 such classes, but only [`Tuple2`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L19) is annotated to specialize (optimize) for primitive types. Anything from [`Tuple3`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/Tuple3.scala#L20) onwards, will box the primitives.

Comment: @Kigyo I don't know for sure, I presume it's the number of the generated .class files of anything above `Tuple2`. Basically, the Scala compiler will generate a new class for each combination of primitive and reference types. There are 9 primitive types (unit, boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float and double) plus 1 reference type. `Tuple2` takes two params. To account for all possible combinations, the compiler has to generated 10^2 classes. This is already a big number. Imagine for `Tuple3`, `Tuple4` or goodness forbid, `Tuple22`.

Comment: There's undergoing research for a better solution, though. It is a compiler plugin, so you can actually try it today, but it'll only work with new classes. http://scala-miniboxing.org/