# Why does this not type check?

Tags: scala

Why does the following code fail to type check:

```
var a = Map.empty[String, Integer]
var b: Integer = a.getOrElse("", 0)
b += 1
b = b + 1
val c: Integer = a.getOrElse("", 0) + 1
```

The first four lines are fine but the last line fails with “Type mismatch: expected String actual Int”. Surely this is doing the same thing as lines 2 & 4 combined?

Comment: The misleading error is from the `any2StringAdd` implicit in `Predef`. You might like to compile with `-Yno-predef` to avoid such surprises, and explicitly import implicits that you actually want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Int` instead of `Integer`:

```
var a = Map.empty[String, Int]
var b: Int = a.getOrElse("", 0)
b += 1
b = b + 1
val c: Int = a.getOrElse("", 0) + 1
```

`Int` and `Integer` are not the same type in Scala.  From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269170/what-is-are-differences-between-int-and-integer-in-scala) post:

> Integer is just an alias for java.lang.Integer. Int is the Scala integer with the extra capabilities.

So what's happening is that when you do `a.getOrElse("", 0)`, the return type is the common super type of `Integer` and `Int`, which is `Any`.  Then you try to add `to an`Any`, which doesn't work!

Comment: As an addition for future debugging. If you look at the type for the original getOrElse, you'll see that it is an Any.

Comment: Side note: `Integer` is not an alias for `j.l.Integer`, it is `j.l.Integer` which is automatically imported by the compiler.