# Scala tree processing

Tags: scala

Can someone please help me with this exercise from Scala for the impatient?

```
sealed abstract class BinaryTree
case class Leaf(value: Int) extends BinaryTree
case class Node(kids: BinaryTree*) extends BinaryTree

def leafSum(t: BinaryTree): Integer = t match {
    case Node(kids @ _*) => kids.map(leafSum).sum
    case Leaf(n) => n
}

leafSum(Node(Node(Leaf(3), Leaf(8)), Leaf(2), Node(Leaf(5))))
```

I have this error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Integer]
        case Node(kids @ _*) => kids.map(leafSum).sum
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `leafSum` function returns `Integer` instead of `Int`:

```
def leafSum(t: BinaryTree): Int = t match {
    case Node(kids @ _*) => kids.map(leafSum).sum
    case Leaf(n) => n
}
```

`Integer` is just an alias for `java.lang.Integer` and is not the Scala integer type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1269170/1743880) for more info on the difference between `Int` and `Integer`.