# Passing Scala objects as Java Object to Java methods

Tags: scala

I have a Java method which takes in a java.lang.Object.
Now I'm trying to pass a Scala Int to it, but the compiler complains about type mismatch of Int and Object.

This feels quite strange as I suppose a Scala Int inherits from AnyRef and should be the same as java.lang.Object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the differences between Int and Integer in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269170/what-is-the-differences-between-int-and-integer-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

Scala `Int` is not extending `AnyRef`, though - it extends `AnyVal`, which is not cast-compatible with java.lang.Object, and is more like Java `int`. Scala also have `Integer` class, which is just an alias for `java.lang.Integer` - use that one if you need to pass it as an object.

Answer (score 1):

There're two braches of Scala classes inherited from the Scala root class - Any:

1. AnyVal: All value based types, e.g. Int, Byte, Double... etc. This is the counterpart of Java raw value classes, i.e. int, float... etc.
2. AnyRef: All reference based types, e.g. String, List, including boxed Java types, such as java.lang.Integer... etc.

(See diagram in https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html)

The AnyRef is equivalent to java.lang.Object. Therefore, when calling Java methods taking Object, a AnyVal cannot be directly transferred before boxing. This can be done through explicit type declaration:

JavaClass.methodWithObject(10: java.lang.Integer)

More discussion refer to:
[Result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546299/result-type-of-an-implicit-conversion-must-be-more-specific-than-anyref)